# Captcha/JQuery - Click simulation only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha, captcha

Hello fellow stack overflowers. I'm using JQuery to simulate a click on an invisible button that's linked with reCaptcha. Multiple buttons need to be attached to reCaptcha and you can only have one reCaptcha in each page. So, I created a callback function that detects which button is pressed. Here is how I did that:

HTML:

```
<div class="invisible">
    <button class="g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="..."
    data-callback="captcha_callback"
    data-badge="inline"
    data-type="image"
    id="btn_captcha"></button>
</div>
```

Click event + click simulation:

```
$("#review_send").on("click", function() {
    alert("HI");
    $("#btn_captcha").data("button-pressed", "review");
    $("#btn_captcha").click();
    $("#btn_captcha").blur();
});
```

reCaptcha callback:

```
var captcha_callback = function(response) {
  if($("#btn_captcha").data("button-pressed") === "mail") {
    alert($("#btn_captcha").data("button-pressed"));
    send_contact_mail(response);
  } else if($("#btn_captcha").data("button-pressed") === "review") {
    alert($("#btn_captcha").data("button-pressed"));
    send_review(response);
  }
};
```

What happens is; when I click `#review_send` for the first time everything works: It first alerts "HI" and then "review".. But when I press `#review_send` a second time I only get the alert with "HI".

I have discovered that the click works again after waiting a while.

Is this something JQuery/Javascript related, has it something to do with reCaptcha or does reCaptcha have a timeout?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Soo, I made this workaround because I thought that you can't have multiple recaptcha on the same page. However, I figured out that there is a way to have multiple of them.

You can render reCaptcha's and reset them (both with javascript):

```
var widget1 = grecaptcha.render("divID", {
    siteKey: "...",
    type: 'image',
    callback: function(response) {
        send_review(response);
    }
});
```

Reset:

```
grecaptcha.reset(widget1);
```

I only have to check which button I pressed to render in the correct div and/or reset the correct reCaptcha.

Comment: Nice,, was working on a sollution but couldn't figure it out!